# How to take a word after word in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input and I need to take the word after a word in JavaScript. I am trying to think how create a regexp to do this, but I'm not getting on the logic.

One example of user input:

```
input reg a,
input b,
input int p, f, g,
output logic c,
output k;
```

So, I have a word (`input`, `output`), that will be followed for a type (or suppressed) then a name of variable until get a `;`. So I need to do a regexp where after the user finish to write the code, it returns to me the name of inputs and outputs. In the example, it should return something like `a,b,p,f,g,c,k`.

Please any ideas how to do this?

Comment: you can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) like this `val = val.replace('input ', '');` or you can parse regexp as argument of `replace`

Comment: How I answer to amflare, the problem is that will exist more text before "input" and more after "output" so I have to be sure that the text I take is just before these keywords, and assume that can be a word before the word I want, or not e.g. "input int a", "input b", "input logic a,b,c".. In this case a need to take the "a" after int, the b after the input, and the a,b,c after logic. And in your example it considers that I have one blank space after input, but the user can put two for example. Anyway the problem is words after and before these inputs and outputs. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It does not need regex, you can solve it with javascript

```
var string = userInput.split(' ');
var inputOutput = string[0];
var wordAfter = string[1];
```

That's slightly verbose and will still work if you leave out the second line.

Comment: I thought about this.. But the problem is that will exist more text before "input" and more after "output" so I have to be sure that the text I take is just before these keywords, and assume that can be a word before the word I want, or not e.g. "input int a", "input b", "input logic a,b,c".. In this case a need to take the "a" after int, the b after the input, and the a,b,c after logic. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 var value_ = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
 var varArr = [];
 for(var i=0; i<value_.length; i++){
    if(value_.charAt(i)=="," || value_.charAt(i)==";" ){
      varArr.push(value_.charAt(i-1));
    }
 }
```

see this link : https://plnkr.co/edit/QOiakDJg4dR3BMTmGCRQ?p=preview

Comment: For the example this worked fine! But I really need to find those keywords or something like, because of this I thought about regEx, the ideia is to take the code of some user and take those words after word. One example of a "complete" code that the user could write can be found here: https://plnkr.co/edit/PC9ldSUlj8yXO3wBsJPf?p=preview and in this case unfortunately this logic doesn't work. Thanks for helping.